# spring boot native with hazelcast: NoSuchMethodError

Tags: hazelcast, spring-native

Starting with `Spring Boot 3.2.2` and `Spring Cloud 2023.0.0`
and native configuration `src/main/resources/META-INF/native-image/reflect-config.json`:

```
[
{"name": "com.hazelcast.map.IMap", "allDeclaredMethods": true, "allDeclaredFields": true, "allDeclaredConstructors": true}
]
```

I get the following exception:

```
2024-01-24 11:05:51.221 ERROR 591197 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.cache.CacheMetricsRegistrarConfiguration': Instantiation of supplied bean failed
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
......
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: no such method: com.hazelcast.map.IMap.getName()String/invokeInterface
        at java.base@21.0.1/java.lang.invoke.MemberName.makeAccessException(MemberName.java:915)
        at java.base@21.0.1/java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:994)
        at java.base@21.0.1/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.resolveOrFail(MethodHandles.java:3750)
        at java.base@21.0.1/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.findVirtual(MethodHandles.java:2767)
        at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.cache.HazelcastIMapAdapter.resolveIMapMethod(HazelcastIMapAdapter.java:257)
        ... 52 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.hazelcast.map.IMap.getName()
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.methodhandles.Util_java_lang_invoke_MethodHandleNatives.resolve(Target_java_lang_invoke_MethodHandleNatives.java:335)
        at java.base@21.0.1/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.resolve(MethodHandleNatives.java:213)
        at java.base@21.0.1/java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolve(MemberName.java:962)
        at java.base@21.0.1/java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:991)
        ... 55 common frames omitted
```

I have changed the `reflect-config.json`, use `RuntimeHintsRegistrar`, but I still get the same error.

Comment: You don't provide enough details when this happens exactly. The generic answer would be some classpath issue where a different version of those classes is present.